# BUG? Product new from date

Tags: magento2, magento-community, bug

I'm running Magento ver. 2.3.5-p1. I have three stores running on one website

When I set a new from date in a specific store scope for a product, on save Magento updates all store scopes.

Bug or by design?

Comment: The obviously makes it impossible for me to use the Magento new product widget on the front end to display new products per store

Comment: Please check this post if it helps! http://mageguides.com/how-to-set-up-new-products-list-in-magento-2/. Select the store views where the widget will be visible. You can choose a specific store view, or “All Store Views.”

Answer (score 0):

Check the scope of the `news_from_date`attribute by clicking on the *Stores* menu and selecting *Attributes* -> *Product*.

Edit the `news_from_date` attribute and under *advanced attribute properties* check the scope of the attribute

- global
- store view
- website

If it is set to *global / website* try setting it to **store view**.

Comment: Thank you paj. Why didn't think of that :)
Attribute was set to website

Comment: Can you please tell me If we will do this, Isn't any effect on our products?